# Difference between JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH and JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX php constants

Tags: php, json, constraints, json-deserialization

What differents between JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH and JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX constants?
[docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) says that JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH - Invalid or malformed JSON and JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX - Syntax error. But "Syntax error" is "Invalid or malformed json", isn't it?

Also we found interesting case
if I run code

```
$str = '{"j": 1 ] }';
$a = json_decode($str);

var_dump($a); //NULL
var_dump(json_last_error()); //2
var_dump(json_last_error_msg()); // State mismatch (invalid or malformed JSON)
```

In PHP 7.0.6 output is

```
NULL
int(2)
string(42) "State mismatch (invalid or malformed JSON)"
```

PHP 5.6.28

```
NULL
int(4)
string(35) "object value separator ',' expected"
```

PHP 5.6.18

```
NULL
int(4)
string(35) "object value separator ',' expected"
```

When I run code here
http://phptester.net/
In any cases output is

```
NULL
int(2)
string(42) "State mismatch (invalid or malformed JSON)"
```

Does anyone know what output is correct and why?

Comment: "The decoding in PHP 5 is handled by a parser based on the JSON_checker by Douglas Crockford. PHP 7 comes with a completely new and improved parser that is specifically written for PHP and licensed under the PHP license. "

Comment: And this service http://phptester.net/ , whey you select php 5.6 use php with version 5.6 with parser from 7-th version?